# jq pass argument as a key to new field

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

I'm trying to add new field in a json file using jq:

```
jq -r --arg k "foo" --arg v "bar"  '.newField += {$k:$v}' myfile
```

But it results in:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.newField += {$k:$v}                
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 1:
.newField += {$k:$v}              
jq: 2 compile errors
```

When I remove key variable like below it works fine:

```
jq -r --arg k "foo" --arg v "bar"  '.newField += {"static_key":$v}' myfile
```

Any idea how to use key name from jq arg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message suggests, put parentheses around the key:

```
jq -r --arg k "foo" --arg v "bar"  '.newField += {($k):$v}' myfile
```

jq requires keys given by expressions (i.e. not literal strings) to be parenthesized ([noted in the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D)).

Comment: Upvoted this as it's a valid solution and is helpful knowledge and a better solution in certain scenarios - however in OPs use case I do think michaels answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

If this helps, using the following uses the arg var itself as json key, and the arg value as the json value:

```
$ jq -r --arg foo "bar"  '.newField += {$foo}' myfile
....
"newField": {
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - David Z's also works but there's little point in assigning them as individual elements